# Solving Legendre Equations with Frobenius

Tags: legendre-polynomials, frobenius-method

I have the following start to an example:

$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+\ell(\ell+1)y=0$ ;

$y= \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+r}$

**Step 1:**(Subbing in y'',y' and y) 
$(1-x^2)[\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}]-2x[\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r-1}]+\ell(\ell+1)[\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+r}=0$

This is then simplified to:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r}$

$\bbox[yellow]{-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r}}+\ell(\ell+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+r}=0$

Then the like terms are further simplified to give:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+r}C_n[\ell(\ell+1)-(n+r)(n+r+1)]=0$

However, I fail to see why the $-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r}$ is not present in the final equation. Why has it disappeared? I've seen this happen in a few examples now but don't understand why it is okay to take it away.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't disappeared.  It was combined with the $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (n+r)(n+r-1) x^{n+r}$.  $$  - (n+r)(n+r-1)  - 2 (n+r) = -(n+r)(n+r+1)$$